# Problems with NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.63.01-grid.run to Deploy to Cloud Run

Tags: deployment, dockerfile, gcloud, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to deploy on google cloud. So, my `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt update 
RUN apt -y install sudo
RUN apt -y install curl
RUN sudo apt install -y build-essential 
RUN curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/nvidia-drivers-us-public/GRID/GRID13.0/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.63.01-grid.run
RUN chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.63.01-grid.run
RUN sudo /bin/bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.63.01-grid.run

FROM python:3.8

RUN adduser meat
RUN passwd -d meat
USER meat
WORKDIR /home/meat
RUN python3 -m venv meat-env
RUN /bin/bash -c "source meat-env/bin/activate"
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

and I got this error:

```
Step 8/20 : RUN sudo /bin/bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.63.01-grid.run
---> Running in 811998f9cea8
Verifying archive integrity...
OK
Uncompressing NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 470.63.01

...............
```

and several dots(.) later

```
[91mError opening terminal: unknown.
[0m
unable to stream build output: The command '/bin/sh -c sudo /bin/bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.63.01-grid.run' returned a non-zero code: 1
Failed to build the app. Error: unable to stream build output: The command '/bin/sh -c sudo /bin/bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.63.01-grid.run' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I made something wrong with my Dockerfile? Or is there a differente way to do the command?

Comment: IIUC you're trying to run a GPU virtualization solution stop a runtime that doesn't expose a GPU. So, that's likely the source of your issue.

Comment: I have a GPU on my server. I tested my codes there and worked. Including that one. But I have problems to do the deploy. Or your point is other?

Comment: I don't know and I've not tried it but you won't be able to run a container image on Cloud Run that depends on a GPU (library) because Cloud Run instances don't expose a GPU

Comment: So, some suggestion? And what means expose a GPU?

Comment: It would be useful if others who are more familiar with NVIDIA GRID weigh in but, my take is, that you can't run this image on Cloud Run. If my understanding is correct, you'll want to consider running it on a VM that has an NVIDIA GPU

Comment: But my VM has a NVIDIA GPU. My problem is the deploy. I thought that I needed install again the NVIDIA GRID.

Comment: @GregRov How do you deploy your app? Are you deploying it in [Cloud Run Fully Managed](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python) or [Cloud Run Anthos(GKE)](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/configuring/compute-power-gpu)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm little dumb and learnign about that, I need to deploying on Cloud Run Anthos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DazWilkin's comment is correct:

> It's not possible to install graphics driver to Cloud Run fully managed because it doesn't expose any GPU.

You should deploy it in Cloud Run Anthos(GKE). But you'll need to configure your GKE Cluster to install your GPU, According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/configuring/compute-power-gpu), you should follow the steps:

1. [Add a GPU-enabled node pool to your GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#create).

> In this step, you can enable Enable Virtual Workstation (NVIDIA GRID). Please choose a GPU such as NVIDIA Tesla T4, P4 or P100 to enable NVIDIA GRID.

2. [Install NVIDIA's device drivers to the nodes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#installing_drivers).

You can now create a service that will consume GPUs and deploy the image to Cloud Run for Anthos:

3. [Setting up your service to consume GPUs](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/configuring/compute-power-gpu#setting)